# Transaction atomicity in Spring

Tags: java, sql, spring, transactions

What does transaction atomicity in SQL/Spring mean and what does it mean not?

I'm thinking of the following case. Correct me if I am wrong:

This code is incorrect:

```
@Transactional
public void voteUp(long fooId) {
    Foo foo = fooMapper.select(fooId); // SELECT * FROM foo WHERE fooId == #{fooId}
    foo.setVotes(foo.getVotes() + 1);
    fooMapper.update(foo); // UPDATE foo SET votes = #{votes} (...) WHERE fooId == #{fooId}
}
```

Even though its transactional it doesn't mean the value of "votes" will be always incremented by one, if voteUp is called concurrently on many machines/in many threads? If it was like this, it would mean that only one transaction can be executed at a time, causing the efficiency to go down (especially if code of voteUp does more stuff in transaction)?

The only correct way to do it is like this (?):

```
/* not necessarily */ @Transactional 
public void voteUp(long fooId) {
    fooMapper.voteUp(fooId); // UPDATE foo SET votes = votes + 1 WHERE fooId == #{fooId}
}
```

In the examples I used myBatis for connection to database, but I think the question stays the same if I used hibernate or plain SQL statements.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Isolation level determines how reliable the view of the data is within the transaction. The most reliable isolation level is serializable (which does impact the database's performance), but the usual default is [read-committed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_%28database_systems%29#Read_committed):

> In this isolation level, a lock-based concurrency control DBMS implementation keeps write locks (acquired on selected data) until the end of the transaction, but read locks are released as soon as the SELECT operation is performed (so the non-repeatable reads phenomenon can occur in this isolation level, as discussed below). As in the previous level, range-locks are not managed.
>
> Putting it in simpler words, read committed is an isolation level that guarantees that any data read is committed at the moment it is read. It simply restricts the reader from seeing any intermediate, uncommitted, 'dirty' read. It makes no promise whatsoever that if the transaction re-issues the read, it will find the same data; data is free to change after it is read.

In the first example, between the select and the update, some other process can change the value of the counter: the select happens, then some other process changes the value of the counter, then the update acts on the changed row.

Changing the isolation level to repeatable-read should make sure that the increment in the first example works correctly. Of course the second example is correct as it stands and is a better solution.

Comment: Big thanks for the answer. Could you elaborate a little about "Changing the isolation level to repeatable-read should make sure that the increment in the first example works correctly."? I have read a little about how locking on this level looks and if I get it right right it puts an exclusive lock only on update statement but allows concurrent reads. So if firstly two transactions do the select and then both the update (2nd one updates after the 1st one ends, but both selects have been done before any update) won't it result in both of them setting the same value of 'votes'?

Comment: @Arsen: with repeatable read it should lock both the reads and writes and hold those until the end of the transaction. you're describing the behavior for read-committed. with repeatable read the second transaction won't get the read lock until the first transaction is committed.

Answer (score 5):

`@Transactional` in that case is used to manage SQL Transactions, it doesn't add any thread safety. The Spring transaction manager doesn't really do much except ask the database to start a new transaction, so you need to refer to the documentation of your RDBMS and read about its transaction semantics.

So yes, there would be a race condition in your first example even though the SELECT and UPDATE are part of the same transaction. There are two possible solutions to your problem :

1- Row locking : Acquiring a lock on the row you're about to modify would prevent any other SQL transaction from modifying its value.

2- Optimistic locking : Optimistic locking doesn't actually use any locks. What you do is that you use a value that you know for sure will change whenever that row is updated. For example you could re-write your update statement to:

```
UPDATE foo SET votes = #{votes} (...) WHERE fooId == #{fooId} AND votes = #{oldNoOfVotes}
```

If no row is updated it means another process has already changed the value of that row and you can then either retry or throw an exception.

Answer (score 4):

According to [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#tx-decl-explained), when you annotate a method with @Transactional, Spring creates a proxy with same interface(s) as the your annotated class. And when you invoke methods of you object, all invocations pass thru proxy object. Proxy object wraps transactional methods of your class in try catch construction. Your original object's code:

```
@Transactional
public void voteUp(long fooId) {
    Foo foo = fooMapper.select(fooId); // SELECT * FROM foo WHERE fooId == #{fooId}
    foo.setVotes(foo.getVotes() + 1);
    fooMapper.update(foo); // UPDATE foo SET votes = #{votes} (...) WHERE fooId == #{fooId}
}
```

In proxy object will be look about like this:

```
//It's all approximately just to show you a way how Spring does it. 
public void voteUp(long fooId) {
    EntityTransaction tx = em.getTransaction();
    tx.begin();
    try{
       originalObject.voteUp(fooId);
       tx.commit();
    }catch(Exception e){
       tx.rallback();
       throw e;
    }
 }
```

So, even if `voteUp` is called concurrently on many machines/in many threads,  value of "votes" will be always incremented by one. Because transaction in one thread will block table for write data from other threads.

You are right: if `voteUp` method will take a long time, it will be causing that efficiency will go down. That means you methods, annotated by @Transactional should not take a long time.

And you right you can update your database records without selection, if your ORM library allows this way.

Comment: *Because transaction in one thread will block table for write data from other threads.* - DO you have any reference for this?

Comment: @TheLostMind -http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/set-transaction.html - look at REPEATABLE READ behavior when update, delete.

Answer (score 1):

**It is not just about atomicity.** A standard DB transaction must have the following traits:

- Atomic
- Consistent
- Isolated
- Durable

These are the "ACID" requirements. What you marked about "incorrect" *is in fact still atomic, but is not isolated*. to make it *isolated* (so concurrent updates give you still the correct result) you can either delegate the concurrency handling to the DB (`set vote = vote+1`) or use a feature of your framework to handle isolation correctly.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_transaction